# How to get active browser info along with active session ID using java\command line

Tags: java, session, browser, command-line, powershell-2.0

I've to get all active browsers that are opened in the local machine along with corresponding session ids.

I've made little research and i do find the below link.

[It's giving the active browser name which is not enough though](http://corejavaexample.blogspot.in/2013/06/how-to-show-browser-infonameversion-and.html)

I know there is some plugin's available to get the sessions but i need to do it programmatically.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: it's **impossible**.

Long answer: Nothing distinguish browser from any other program. In fact many programs have browser functionality embedded in it.

If you define browser as one of known program such as "Firefox", "Chrome", "IE" etc. than you can do something to achieve some result.

First of all: forget about `Java`, you need to work with `Win-API` and `Java` is not best solution to do it.

You can enumerate process and find browsers by executable name.

Then you can check each browser documentation to find if there any integration API. Each browser will have its own API (or do not have).

Then using this API you can extract what is available.

So it will be hard if even possible to get what you want.